# Set default properties in a library with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have many different services using spring-boot. I'd like to set up some configuration that is common for each, but allow the services to have their own properties and override them if they want. Example properties include spring.show_banner, management url ones, etc.

How can I do this? If I have the following:

- service-common with src/main/resources/application.yml with default properties
- service1 with src/main/resources/application.yml with its own properties

I'd like them to be merged with the service1 version taking precedence. Instead, it seems that only the first one found on the classpath is used.

(Alternatively, using @Configuration classes would be even better, but I'm not sure they can be used to define many of the properties)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are several options available to you, all based on the [order in which property sources are considered](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

If your common library is responsible for creating the `SpringApplication` it can use `setDefaultProperties`. These values can be overridden by your services' `application.properties`.

Alternatively, your library could use `@PropertySource` on one of its `@Configuration` classes to configure, for example, `library.properties` as a source. Again, these properties could then be overriden in your services' `application.properties`.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Your second approach will work for me. I was assuming that the default spring-boot would have a property source of classpath*/application.yml (with the asterisk to find multiple matches); but I guess that could introduce issues.

Comment: I tried this approach and it seems as if it does not work for all properties. For example, the `spring.main.banner-mode=off`does not seem to work. Whereas other properties are fine. I assume that some properties are used so early in the startup phase that they cannot be set via PropertySource in an external library? Is that understanding correct and if yes, what are the only  ways to set those properties and which properties are affected?

Comment: Whereas another property "spring.output.ansi.enabled" seems to work only when passed via command line property and when adding it to the application.yml, but not when it is part of the default properties. This is really confusing because those settings do work or do not work, depending on how they get specified.

Comment: This works only for .properties files, [not for .yml files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings).

Comment: If I went this route with library.properties --> is there a way to specify environment specific library properties as well? So if the consuming application is running application-stage.properties, is there a simple way to select the library-stage.properties?

Comment: @xheyhenry yes that should be possible if you annotate you library `@Configuration` class with `@Profile("stage")`

Comment: `@PropertySource` doesn't appear to have any support for `spring.config.import` style imports.

Comment: @AdrianBaker Correct. That's to be expected as `@PropertySource` is a Spring Framework feature and knows nothing about Spring Boot's `spring.config.import` support.

Comment: Note that calling `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties()` at startup only works when the app is started that way — which means it probably won't work for unit tests, for apps run within a Tomcat server,…

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by merging them.

But I'm assuming that in the end, you are describing the situation where you have profile-specific configuration. Because, any properties that are specific to a certain service can be managed/injected using Spring profiles, **which will always take precedence over default property files** (see [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)).

For example, you can have the file `application-service1.properties` which would automatically be used when you run your app with the property `spring.profiles.active=service1`, which can be specified in the command line and [other places](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).
If you don't specify this property, Spring Boot will fallback to the default `application.properties` file.

And you can of course write the common properties in both files:

application.properties:

```
service.url=http://localhost:8080/endpoint
service.user=admin
service.password=admin
```

application-service1.properties:

```
service.url=http://api.service.com/endpoint
service.user=admin
service.password=aosdnoni3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent envEvent = (ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) event;
            ConfigurableEnvironment env = envEvent.getEnvironment();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            //set props as desired
            env.getPropertySources()
                    .addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("customname", props));
    }
}
```

Then in src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories, add line:
`org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=mypackage.MyApplicationListener`