# @ConstructorBinding with immutable properties don't work with @Value in Spring Boot Kotlin @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Spring Boot supports Kotlin `data` classes for `@ConfigurationProperties`.

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")
data class AppProperties (
    val something: String
)
```

But `val` and `@ConstructorBinding` has some limitations. You cannot alias one variable to another. Let's say you're running in Kubernetes and want to capture the hostname, which is given by the env var `HOSTNAME`. The easiest way to do this is to apply `@Value("\${HOSTNAME}:)"` to a property, but it only works for a mutable property and without constructor binding.

The Spring Boot GitHub issue tracker says:

> STOP!! Please ask questions about how to use something, or to understand why something isn't
> working as you expect it to, on Stack Overflow using the spring-boot tag.

So, is this a known limitation or should I create a ticket for them to fix it?

Edit:
Opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25552

Comment: I don't think it's something to be fixed. Don't get me wrong, but I believe you are misusing it. Instead of creating "aliases" for the Properties' class, you can rely on its power. For instance, you can set the property you need to your `application.properties` just by doing something like `prefix.something=${HOSTNAME}`

Comment: @MarcosBarbero "_I believe you are misusing it_" Misuse is a strong word for saying you've a different opinion. I'm aware of what I can do in the `application.properties`, but there's no reason to not to be able to do it in the code, especially because you can do this in Java just fine. You're entitled to your opinion, but unless you can prove that it's a misuse, I recommend avoiding to say so.

Comment: Also, if it's a library, there's no `application.properties`, so try again.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my first language, and I had no intention whatsoever to disrespect you at any moment. I still stand by what I have just said. In other words, you shouldn't be mixing `@Value` inside a `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

Comment: Okay, if it's a library, as you say, and based on the described, it will be used by a spring-boot application. You have a few options to achieve what you want. This link may be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892948/set-default-properties-in-a-library-with-spring-boot?answertab=active#tab-top, doing what you are trying to do is not one of them.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero thanks for your comment, but no. Just because you’ve not done it in a certain way, doesn’t make it wrong. I’ll create a ticket for Boot.

Comment: Do you know the guy in the link above? He's literally one of the lead developers in the Spring Boot team, but yeah, good luck with your ticket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@ConfigurationProperties` is [an alternative to `@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) and the two are not designed to be used together. It may work with JavaBean-style binding but that would be by accident rather than by design and it shouldn't be relied upon.

Instead of using `@Value` to alias something bound via `@ConfigurationProperties`, it's recommended that you do so via some other means. For example you could use one of the approaches suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28894906/1384297) that Marcos Barbero linked to in the comments on your question. Alternatively, you could take some inspiration from [this example in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-short-command-line-arguments) and use a placeholder in `application.properties`:

```
prefix.something=${hostname}
```

Another option would be to register via `META-INF/spring.factories` an implementation of `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that adds a `PropertySource` to the environment to set up the desired aliasing. For the time being, this is probably the best approach if you want to do something in a reusable library. There's [an open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24688) to remove some of the ceremony that's currently involved.