# Spring boot doesn't resolve a default value in a @Value property in a dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, properties, dependencies

Edit: Another thing I should note is I'm running this out of Eclipse. I wonder if that's somehow causing an issue.

Original post:
I'm having trouble getting a placeholder to resolve in Spring Boot.

Here is the placeholder I'm testing:

```
@Value("${influxdb.port:8086}")
private String port;
```

This above exists in what I'll call component Foo of the application.

Component Bar uses Foo as a dependency specified in pom.xml. It invokes a method from Foo as follows:

```
InfluxDBClient client = bipInfluxDBClientService.getInfluxClient();
```

However, Bar doesn't start due to an unresolved dependency:

```
2022/11/11 16:26:04.571 | ERROR | main | c.s.i.c.c.ApplicationErrorListener] | !!!!!! Something is not working as expected so the application is stopping. Error: Error creating bean with name 'influxUtilsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'influxdb.port' in value "${influxdb.port}" !!!!!!
```

If I include influxdb.port in the application.properties file of Bar, it works. Or if I include it in an external properties file that is read by Bar on startup, it also works.

However, I would like the default value to be specified in the code of Foo, not Bar.

Why is it not resolving this dependency?

Comment: Is your Foo dependency actually custom spring boot starter with defined autoconfiguration?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It's a bunch of home-grown maven projects which provide a common set of functionality for various projects. Another thing I should note is I'm running this out of Eclipse. I wonder if that's somehow causing an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default properties in a library with spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892948/set-default-properties-in-a-library-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Sorry, it turned out to be user error. I had a class of exactly the same name which I moved to the platform and forgot to delete it. It was was actually the one causing the crash. It was difficult to figure out because the spring name I was using was the same. It was pretty confusing.